# python subprocess and grep command

Tags: python, linux, bash

I am writing a script program with Python. Within this program, I need to get grep result of a filename and extract filenames from it.
I am stuck with 'grep' right now.
I try to grep a file named NoMoreHotCorner_20151006.T and return the result.
My expected result should be the following:

```
grep: command/CVS: Is a directory
grep: command/obsolete: Is a directory
command/yosemite-2015.K:#p system/NoMoreHotCorner_20151006.T
```

I can guarantee that this file exists and there is no problem in my path.

I can get the desired result by using os.system().

```
>>> import os
>>> from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
>>> from subprocess import CalledProcessError, check_output
>>> string = 'grep '+'NoMoreHotCorner_20151006.T'+' command/*'
>>> os.system(string)
grep: command/CVS: Is a directory
grep: command/obsolete: Is a directory
command/yosemite-2015.K:#p system/NoMoreHotCorner_20151006.T
```

But this function cannot return its output to screen. So I decided to use subprocess.check_output instead. But it raised CalledProcessError.

```
>>> p = check_output(string,shell=True)
grep: command/CVS: Is a directory
grep: command/obsolete: Is a directory
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 573, in check_output
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'grep NoMoreHotCorner_20151006.T command/*' returned non-zero exit status 2
```

So I looked up similar problems at stack overflow and deal with the exception this time. But it only prints the first two lines....

```
>>> try:
...     p = check_output(string,shell=True)
... except CalledProcessError as e:
...     print(e.returncode)
... 
grep: command/CVS: Is a directory
grep: command/obsolete: Is a directory
2
```

So I changed to use Popen this time. However, it still had a problem. After it output first two lines, it run forever.

```
>>> p = Popen(string,shell=True,stdout=PIPE)
>>> grep: command/CVS: Is a directory
grep: command/obsolete: Is a directory

KeyboardInterrupt
```

I am totally stuck at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `p = Popen(string,shell=True,stdout=PIPE)` to `p = Popen(['grep', 'NoMoreHotCorner_20151006.T', 'command/*'],stdout=PIPE)` then use `p.communicate()` to read the output.

Or, use `check_output(['grep', 'NoMoreHotCorner_20151006.T', 'command/*'])`

Comment: Do you mean `p = Popen(['grep', 'NoMoreHotCorner_20151006.T', 'command/*'],stdout=PIPE)`? The argument of command should only take one position. It still doesn't work. `>>> p = Popen(['grep', 'NoMoreHotCorner_20151006.T', 'command/*'],stdout=PIPE) 
>>> grep: command/*: No such file or directory`

Comment: It cannot find the file..`>>> try:                                                                        ...     check_output(['grep', 'NoMoreHotCorner_20151006.T', 'command/*'])
... except CalledProcessError as e:
...     print(e.returncode)
... 
grep: command/*: No such file or directory
2`

Comment: Yes, I made a typo. Args should to be in a list. I just verified and both work on my machine. For the `grep` command, is `command/*` the pattern you want to grep and `NoMoreHotCorner_20151006.T` the file? The pattern needs to be before the file name.

Comment: It still doesn't work. If I use a list rather than a string as the first args, the file cannot even be found. string should also work according to python2.7 documentation about subprocess.check_output.

Answer (score 0):

Also if you need to get you command as string to a list

import shlex
and use shlex.split(command) to get your list